# Inequality $\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+2b}+...+\frac{1}{a+nb}<\frac{n}{\sqrt{a\left( a+nb \right)}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, telescopic-series

> Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R+}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that:
>   $$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+2b}+...+\frac{1}{a+nb}<\frac{n}{\sqrt{a\left( a+nb \right)}}$$

I have a solution using induction, but without induction I can not think of any way to prove this.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: @carmichael561 yes positive real numbers

Comment: Please show your proof by induction?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For positives $a$ and $b$ By C-S we obtain:
$$\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+2b}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a+nb}\right)^2$$

$$\leq n\left(\frac{1}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{1}{(a+2b)^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(a+nb)^2}\right)$$

$$<n\left(\frac{1}{(a+\frac{b}{2})(a+\frac{3b}{2})}+\frac{1}{(a+\frac{3b}{2})(a+\frac{5b}{2})}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(a+\frac{(2n-1)b}{2})(a+\frac{(2n+1)b}{2})}\right)$$

$$=\frac{n}{b}\left(\frac{1}{a+\frac{b}{2}}-\frac{1}{a+\frac{3b}{2}}+\frac{1}{a+\frac{3b}{2}}-\frac{1}{a+\frac{5b}{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a+\frac{(2n-1)b}{2}}-\frac{1}{a+\frac{(2n+1)b}{2}}\right)$$

$$=\frac{n}{b}\left(\frac{1}{a+\frac{b}{2}}-\frac{1}{a+\frac{(2n+1)b}{2}}\right)=\frac{n^2}{(a+\frac{b}{2})(a+\frac{(2n+1)b}{2})}<\frac{n^2}{a(a+nb)}.$$
Done!

Comment: a proof by induction is also possible

Comment: Brilliant proof !

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner Maybe, but whitexlotus wish the proof without induction.

Comment: very very nice @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: +1. Ingenious as usual, and getting a sharper bound, MichaelRozengberg!

Comment: Thanks guys! The telescopic sum forever!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg can you help me in inequality in triangle , I need one hunt !!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof that is an alternative to and perhaps more straightforward than the ingenious one of Michael Rozenberg.

WOLOG, let $a = 1$.
Since
$$1+t<\Big(1+\frac t2\Big)^2,$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac b{1+bi}< \int_0^{bn}\frac1{1+t}\,dt<\int_0^{bn}\frac{1+\frac t2}{(1+t)^\frac32}\,dt =\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t}}\bigg|_{t=0}^{bn}.$$

QED

Indeed, from the derivation above, the left hand side of the original inequality has a tighter upper bound of $\frac1b\ln\big(1+\frac ba n\big)$.